# Participial construction. Can I say like that?

Tags: grammar, participial-phrases, participial

I want to ask about the participial construction. Please check and comment on these 2 sentences.

-Being unable to remember that word, I often feel frustrated.

-Unable to remember that word, I often feel frustrated.

Comment: Both have the default meaning 'As I am never able to remember that word, I often feel frustrated.' Which seems odd. 'Unable to remember the word, he felt frustrated' is an example that sounds more plausible. I prefer the style here to 'Being unable ...'.  However, I'd feel less (!?) qualms about using 'Being unable to meet their demands, he had to sell the business': it's probably the greater formality.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Actually I wanted to say like "When I can't remember that word, I feel stress." But we can't say this with participial construction?

Comment: Both of those variations are grammatical and understandable. (And, as far as I'm concerned, idiomatic and natural. Between the two, if forced, I would personally choose the first version.)

Comment: As I say, the default meaning of both is that you're _never_ able to remember the word. '_As_ I am unable to remember ...', not '_Whenever_ I am unable to remember ...'.